# How do you connect a physical fax machine to receive faxes over RJ11 and transmit the data over USB to a computer?

Tags: usb, modem, fax, rj-11

Is it possible to set up a physical fax machine to receive faxes over [RJ11](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00006HSK6) telephone cable and forward/transmit that received data over [USB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08DK8RPRW) to a computer as a [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) or [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF) file?

Is there a fax machine I can buy that does this, or do I need to individually buy parts separately?

Comment: Assuming this is a desktop computer, you can install a fax modem card and then use Windows Fax Software or third party Fax Software. This will do what you need.  I have eliminated fax because Signed PDF documents are normally acceptable. DocuSign is being increasingly used.

Comment: if you can answer this question with a link to a fax modem card I can mark the answer is correct. Thank you.

Comment: I have posted an answer for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming this is a desktop computer, you can install a fax modem card and then use Windows Fax Software or third party Fax Software. This will do what you need.

I have done this myself and it worked fine when I used it

There are numerous fax modem cards.

Here is one US Robotics (I have used these)

https://www.usr.com/products/56k-dialup-modem/usr5638/

You can search for Fax Modem cards for PC and see numerous brands.

I have eliminated fax because Signed PDF documents are normally acceptable. DocuSign is being increasingly used

Comment: What was the reason for the downvote to a good answer?

Comment: You mean an answer to a question that is out of scope?

Comment: The author asked for an answer and I provided it. No need to downvote it as it was very reasonable to the time period posted.

Comment: I didn't downvote the answer.  Question was closed 2 years ago.

Comment: You answered a question seeking a hardware recommendation.  Had the question been migrated to the proper community it would have likely been better received. **It does not appear the downvote was recent.**